# Why is mat-checkbox inside *ngFor not getting the latest [checked] value from model?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
     >>>>>>>>LINE 2>>>>>>>>>> {{item.checkedOrUnchecked}}
     <mat-checkbox [checked]="item.checkedOrUnchecked"></mat-checkbox>
```

LINE 2 in above code is always in sync with changes done else-where.

However, mat-checkbox is not updated with true/false. Its losing the context here. Even if *ngFor is creating a child-context for every iteration, when LINE 2 is able to pick the latest updates why is mat-checkbox not able to be in sync.

One thing I noticed is, if the initial value of item.checkedOrUnchecked is false and if it is changed to true, mat-checkbox is checked. But, further toggling of item.checkedOrUnchecked from true-to-false or false-to-true doesn't have any affect.

Issue can be replicated here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-checkbox-issue-zyjhd3

Plz can someone advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this :

```
[checked]="item.checkedOrUnchecked"
```

to

```
[(ngModel)]="item.checkedOrUnchecked"
```

---

Here is the working example of it, please have a look :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-checkbox-issue

---

Your demo with issue : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-checkbox-issue-zyjhd3

Issues :

1) Missing `let i =index;` from `*ngFor="let property of properties;let i =index;"`

2) So was not passing correct value from here `saveProperty($event, i)`

3) `this.properties[index][key] = property[key]` , `property[key]` is `string` not `boolean` , so need to be converted to boolean

Solved : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-checkbox-issue-tbutvp

Comment: @nsk, I have also created a demo, please check updated answer.

Comment: Updated question with my demo where am facing actual issue with EventEmitters etc.